# How to passing date parameter using pentaho designer?

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

I have problem how to passing parameter date field database in report.

I have set the parameter like this :-  `X.createDate= ${datetim}` in MySql.

I have also put the parameter setting in pentaho designer. When i run the report. the result not appear.
Below is Screenshot for parameter setting in report:-

[image]

Anybody know about this?.

Answer (score 0):

You set a query on the parameter. If a parameter has a query, the query's results will be used as validation source. Any provided parameter value will be checked and only accepted if it is found in that result-set.

First: Mark the parameter as mandatory, so that you get informed if the reporting engine considers your parameter invalid.

Second: the date-picker does not actually indicate which values are valid or not. So if you indeed only want to select parameters based on the available dates in the database, I would recommend to NOT use the date-picker. Use a drop-down menu instead.